# 178. Rank Scores

Tags: mysql, sql, dense-rank

I tried to solve the question with the subquery approach and I am getting a behaviour I cant understand.

```
select score,
    (select count(distinct s1.score) from scores s1 
     where s1.score > s2.score)+1 as 'rank' 
from scores s2 
order by s2.score desc;
```

The above code runs perfectly but :

- In line 3 of the query if I try to use rank instead of 'rank' leetcode compiler gives an error.
- In the last line if I try to order it by rank it shows an error while rank by score works fine.

Please explain why it is happening.
Many thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Rank is a reserved word in version 8.0.2 see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R

Comment: @P.Salmon Okay, Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: In SQL each type of a quote have its own meaning. Sometimes they may interfere, but the situation when one uses one quote char where another one must be used is not recommended, because this interpretation may differ in future versions or while the settings (SQL Mode primarily) changes. In your particular case you must use backticks for object name (column alias) quoting. And not single quote which is used for a (string, time, etc.) literal quoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in MySQL 8+, `RANK` has become a reserved MySQL keyword.  This is due to that MySQL 8+ introduces an analytic function called `RANK`.  So, if you want to use `RANK` as an alias, you should escape it in backticks or double quotes:

```sql
SELECT score,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s1.score) FROM scores s1
     WHERE s1.score > s2.score) + 1 AS `rank`
FROM scores s2
ORDER BY `rank` DESC;
```